# csv import product variants in odoo8

Tags: csv, odoo

How can I import a list of products with attribute and EAN code via csv in odoo8

I was able to import a product variant with attribute values, but I was not able to specify an EAN per attribute value.  Can someone provide me with a template

EDIT:

First I have to import my attributes. I basically have only colors

```
    name    value_ids/name      value_ids/color       type
Product Shade   1 Red               #f4e1ca      Color
                2 Blue              #e1b181 
                3 Green             #f3f3f4
```

Them I import my products with the attribute values to create variants

```
    name    product_variant_ids/attribute_line_ids/attribute_id 
product_variant_ids/attribute_line_ids/value_ids
    Super Product           Product Shade                         1 Red,2 Blue,3 Green
```

Hear I would like to  import internal reference and EAN code for the variants 1 Red, 2 Blue etc.

Unfortunately I was not able to and on odoo.com nobody could help me either.

I managed to solve the issue be exporting all variants adding EAN and reference to the spreadsheet and reimporting them. That is however not very elegant and since odoo seams to import variants rather strange by jumping ID's, I can not really predict them and create the sheet automatically.

Comment: Can you post the code ?

Comment: What code do you want me to post. Do you have the same problem and want to see my solution or do you think you can help me. I posted that a long time ago and I made some progress in the meantime, but don't have a definitive solution. I will look for my csv template and post it hear later